# What does "sound English" mean?

Tags: meaning

A: "Thank you for all you've done. Without meaning to flatter you, you're a great success as English teacher; the proof is that I, who usually skip class, followed the course up to its end. I'll never forget how supportive you were.
Besides, I apologize profusely for upseting you so often. I regret it, I really do. It was never meant to disrespect you. For me, before being my teacher, you're a friend; that's why I  lacked to respect you as I should've to.
PS : I'd like to make a confession: Did you remember how often I teased you about your age? I'm as old as you!"

B:Sound English

Comment: Huh? Can we have some context please?

Comment: The English teacher is responding to his student's letter; he is saying that the language, the English, of the letter, is sound. In other words: he taught his student well.

Comment: Look at the definitions of 'sound' as an adjective.  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound  In this context it means 'competent'.  The teacher has commented on the soundness (the correctness) of your English and has declined to comment on the content.

Comment: The above is not a question.

Comment: In this case, the response "sound English" may be intended to damn you with faint praise. "Sound English" is not "Good English!" and, in fact, while the English used in A is (mostly) sound, it shouldn't be called good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of theories as to the meaning of B's response:

1. They were complimenting you, saying that your English is sound. Your message was nice and quite formal.
2. They were making fun of you, ironically saying that your English is "sound." Your message was, at times, a little too formal, to the point where it maybe wasn't very sound. For example, "I lacked to respect you as I should've to" sounds very weird and doesn't make too much sense.
3. They told you to "sound more English," again, complaining about your language. If you were confused by the response, I guess this is what you thought it meant. Though, that's highly unlikely, because "sound English" itself doesn't sound like proper English.

Personally, I think B meant to say thank you for your message, and compliment you on your well-polished language.

Answer (score 0):

The English teacher is complimenting your English. It's not perfect, but it is understandable.

Excerpt below from [Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sound):

```
Sound:

3

a :  free from error, fallacy, or misapprehension

b :  exhibiting or based on thorough knowledge and experience...
```